# Why the screen gets half on iphone5?

Tags: html, iphone, viewport, newsletter

Can anyone tell me why every time I view the email on 2 of my iphones. It gives me different result?

I set this in my header

This is an Email Newsletter and the table is set to 100%. Technically, there shoudn't be a problem when displaying on any mobile but in iPhone5 it doesn't display the full width. Anyone could tell me what is going on?

Comment: Fix your code by escaping your header with `\`backticks\``

Comment: Check the width of the parent elements.  Sometimes you even have to apply a style width to the html element too.

Comment: Is it a 100% of view port?

Comment: I set the HTML and Body to width:100% but the screen for iphone5 is still half the size... I only have 1 table that is set to 100% but why is this happening?